# VB.Net - How to scroll through GroupBox

Tags: vb.net

Please excuse my lack of familiarity with vb.net. Just got thrown on a project with no vb.net experience.

I have to add some things to an application that was written by somebody who is no longer in the picture. I have to add more textboxes into a groupbox and when I do that it exceeds the size of the form. How can I make it so that I can scroll through the groupbox?

Comment: What did you try already? can you post some code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GroupBox, as it doesn't derive from ScrollableControl, so itself can't have scrolling functionality.

So...

Place the GroupBox inside a panel, and set the panel `AutoScroll` to `true`.

**Guides:**

[Adding a panel control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4wyhfkbh%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

[Setting properties (of anything)](http://www.functionx.com/vcsharp/windows/propwnd.htm)

Moving content is just simply selecting all the elements you want to move, and click and drag them into the new place.

Comment: Is there a quick and easy way to do that?

Comment: Yeah, add a panel in visual studio, select the group box and the elements. Drag it in to the panel, then click on the panel and set the AutoScroll property.

Answer (score 3):

You could set the `AutoSize` property of the groupbox to `true`, and then set the `AutoScroll` of the form to `true` as well. This should resize the groupbox so that everything in it is visible, and then the form will have a scrollbar. If you don't want to make your form have a scrollbar for some reason, then you could use a panel and set it's `AutoScroll` to True so that just the panel has a scrollbar.

Comment: This looks great in the design view, but when I run the application I can't scroll through the form. If the form is displayed inside of another window(I assume that is another form), could there be an overriding property there that doesn't allow for this?

Comment: So are you saying the form is a MdiChild Form? Or by displayed in another window, do you mean it's displayed in like a printpreviewdialog, for example?

Answer (score 1):

Add a `Panel` with no border inside the `GroupBox` to group your controls (put the controls inside). Then:

```
Panel1.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Vertical
```

Or even `ScrollBars.Auto`.

Answer (score 1):

GroupBox doesnt have scrolling functionality itself.  Most likely most simple solution here is   to just put a Panel inside the groupbox and add the textboxes to the panel instead.